# Do I have to use nan, ka, or both to ask a question?

Tags: grammar, syntax, questions

I'm going through Genki, and for questions, it gives the example,

りゅうがくせいです (I am an international student) can be turned into a question by adding ka to the end.

りゅうがくせいですか (Are you an international student?)

But then it starts saying that you use nan desu ka to make a question, like in,

せんこうはなんですか (What is your major?)

So when do I use na desu ka, or just ka, or just nan, or what?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quickly find a duplicate, but I wanted to address what Genki had to say (my emphasis):

> It's very easy to form questions in Japanese. Basically, all you need to do is add *ka* at the end of a **statement**.
>
> りゅうがくせいです。
>   Ryuugakusee desu.
>   (I am) an international student.
>
> りゅうがくせいです**か**。
>   Ryuugakusee desu ka.
>   (Are you) an international student?

It goes on to point out that this was a "yes/no" question. In other words, you can take a basic statement (that would be the answer to a yes/no question) and turn it into a question by adding か at the end.

It then follows with

> Question sentences **may also** contain a "question word" like *nan* (what). In this lesson, we learn how to ask, and answer, questions using the following **question words**: *nanji* (what time), *nansai* (how old), *nannensee* (what year in school).
>
> せんこうは  **なん**ですか。
>   Senkoo wa  nan desu ka
>   What is your major?
>
> (せんこうは)   **えいご**です。
>   (Senkoo wa)   eego desu.
>   (My major) is English.

In other words, when you want to ask WH-question like *what?*, you use a question word like the above. Notice that the first question was not a WH-question. So a WH-word was not used.

For context, you will later learn to drop certain words in casual speech, like です and か in questions.